# Blender 2.82a I can't render grease pencil shots because of emptys

Tags: rendering, empty

I parent every shot to empty that parented to one lead empty like Worthikids in his first tutorial, but starting with shot 3 when I move an empty and start render they stuck in each other.

I tried to move them around, they are moving, but after render shots with empties go on original position. The camera is ok.

[Link to Blend file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1smAsUCYgG4YlFTOxoZO3vam-bNHION9U?usp=sharing)

[Link to Worthikids tutorial](https://youtu.be/l46T7fJ7FmE?t=4189)

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately we aren't sitting in front of your PC so can't see your Blender scene and have no idea what you've done! We also have no idea what "Worthikids" is so an image or link to that might be useful. If your Blend file isn't too large it would also be helpful if you could share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Ok. I'm not too familiar with Grease pencil myself so I've added your links into your question which should mean that it's resubmitted and someone else here may be able to help..

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.